# Delphi ZipMaster: how can I create a zip file from stream and hold it as a stream

Tags: delphi, zip, zipstream

Experts,

I have the following problem. I try to find a solution to create a zip file as a stream, but the zip file should not be stored physically and should exist only as a stream.

I have tried with the following code example, but it doesn't work. If I do it this way, an error message blobs up:

> The archive is corrupted or do not contains files.

The zip library that I use is ZipMaster - DelphiZip (http://www.delphizip.org/).

```
function StreamToZipStream( const InStream: TStream; out OutStream: TStream). Boolean;
var
  ZipMaster1 : TZipMaster;
begin
  //wird nie benutzt: result := 0;
  ZipMaster1 := TZipMaster.create(nil);
  try
    ZipMaster1.DLLDirectory := GetModuleDir;    
    ZipMaster1.AddCompLevel := 9;         // highest compression
    ZipMaster1.AddOptions  := [AddHiddenFiles];

    InStream.Position := 0;
    ZipM.AddStreamToStream(TMemoryStream(InStream)); 
    //after add the inStream to the ZipMaster1.ZipStream
    // save it to the OutStream ?    
    ZipMaster.ZipStream.SaveToStream(OutStream);
    result := ZipMaster1.ErrCode = 0;
  finally
    ZipMaster1.free;
  end;
end;

...

InStream := TMemoryStream.Create; 
OutStream := TMemoryStream.Create; 
try 
  //load a file to MemoryStream
  InStream.LoadFromFile('File.txt');   

  //ZipMaster operation to create  a zip stream, that I can save as .zip from this stream
  StreamToZipStream(aInStream, aOutStream ) ;

  // I get a file 'File.zip' with the right file size, but I can not handle this file.
  // an error message "the archive is corrupted" poped up if I try to do some operations with.
  OutStream.SaveToFile('File.zip'); 
finally 
  InStream.Free; 
  OutStream.Free; 
end;
```

Comment: `OutStream` and `aOutStream` are two separate stream objects. You save the zip to one, but then save the other to file. Same with `InStream` and `aInStream` for loading.

Comment: thank you for the hint. I made a mistake while writing this code snippet. But it's only here and not in my main program.

Comment: A zip file contains files not just file contents. Your making a zipstream which is just the contents of a file.

Comment: Yes I know. I found out that the ZipMaster do not support this stream to stream thing. It's not possible to create a zip archive as a stream, excepted save it to the hard disk and after that load it to the stream. But that it's not the solution for my problem. 
Thank you for your replay.